# Custom ordering of fields inside Formalchemy Fieldset

Tags: python, formalchemy

We have a pretty long table where a row should be rendered using FormAlchemy.
The requirement is that the 'title' column should be displayed first and all other fields should follow in alphabetical order. Is there a straight forward way to move and sort fields in FormAlchemy. I need a generic solution here....is touching the FieldSet._render_fields OrderedDict appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Passing the include paramter to the configure function of the fieldset will allow you to set the order. Are you looking to set it programatically? If not you can do

```
fieldset.configure(include=[fieldset.title, fieldset.a_field, fieldset.b_field, fieldset.c_field])
```